# Realm EXC_BAD_ACCESS after using new notification functions from from 0.98.0

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, realm

During delete object from realm I write transaction in main thread. And I have list observer that uses new api from 0.98.0 `addNotificationBlock`
Please can you assist why this EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens, and how to prevent it. Is there any restriction that I should not write in main thread?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happened as I did not unsubscribe from all notification for removed object